# Fetching JMS Header in Apache Flume

Tags: apache, hadoop, ibm-mq, flume, flume-ng

I am trying to consume JMS messages (IBM Websphere MQ) using Apache Flume and storing the data to HDFS. While reading the message, i am only able to see the body of the message and not the header content of the message.

Is it possible to read the jms message with the header property using Apache Flume?

My configuration:

```
# Source definition
u.sources.s1.type=jms
u.sources.s1.initialContextFactory=ABC
u.sources.s1.connectionFactory=<my connection factory>
u.sources.s1.providerURL=ABC
u.sources.s1.destinationName=r1
u.sources.s1.destinationType=QUEUE
# Channel definition
u.channels.c1.type=file
u.channels.c1.capacity=10000000
u.channels.c1.checkpointDir=/checkpointdir
u.channels.c1.transactionCapacity=10000
u.channels.c1.dataDirs=/datadir
# Sink definition
u.sinks.r1.type=hdfs
u.sinks.r1.channel=c1
u.sinks.r1.hdfs.path=/message/%Y%m%d
u.sinks.r1.hdfs.filePrefix=event_
u.sinks.r1.hdfs.fileSuffix=.xml
u.sinks.r1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
u.sinks.r1.hdfs.writeFormat=Text
u.sinks.r1.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp=TRUE
```

Comment: What header content are you referring to?  MQMD or Named Properties?

Comment: @Roger I am looking for both MQMD and Named Properties. Basic idea is to store the header contents from JMS MQ.

Comment: For Named Properties just do: msg.getStringProperty("name") and for MQMD following the information here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032350_.htm

Comment: The Flume 1.5.0 User Guide states related to the JMS Source: "In all cases, the properties in the message are added as headers to the FlumeEvent."

Comment: @JoshMc can you give the url for the same?

Comment: http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#converter

Comment: Did you resolve your question?  Was the data all ready storing the header information as headers to the FlumeEvent?

Comment: If @Marco99's answer helped solve your issue you should accept it, if you do not the bounty you put up will go to no one and is wasted since you do not get those points back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few types of JMS messages as in "Table 30–2 JMS Message Types" [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnces/index.html).

The Flume `DefaultJMSMessageConverter` uses `TextMessage` as in [here](https://apache.googlesource.com/flume/+/d9061a037662dd0a37c44ba5f9cf705d21c84987/flume-ng-sources/flume-jms-source/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/source/jms/DefaultJMSMessageConverter.java) and is given below for your reference:

```
...
else if(message instanceof TextMessage) {
      TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage)message;
      event.setBody(textMessage.getText().getBytes(charset));
    } 
...
```

[TextMessage](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/TextMessage.html) offers only body of the message.

IMHO, you have two options:

1. If at all possible, send the message-header, header-value pair in the body itself and use the "DefaultJMSMessageConverter" as is.
2. Build your own "flume-jms-source.jar" by writing a custom JMSMessageConverter and type-cast the "message" to [javax.jms.Message](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html), get the JMS headers, set them in `SimpleEvent`.

Hope this gives some direction.